# Number of ways to select $K$ people from $N$ people such that at least $r$ people are there in between them

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Number of ways to select $K$ people from $N$ people (who are aligned in a line)  such that at least $r$ people are there in between them

Ex: I want to select 3 people from 10 people (who are aligned in a line) such that at least 2 people should be there between the selected people

May I know the resources for learning this type of problems , also what is the solution if people are arranged in circular manner

Comment: What do you mean by "between them"

Comment: consider if I selected x,y persons from a line, so there should be at least r people between x and y

Comment: Since $K>2$ is possible, do you mean $r$ people between any adjacent pair of selected people?  Or do you mean $r$ people between the leftmost and rightmost selected people?  In both cases, do the selected people themselves count as part of the $r$?  If you find it hard to explain, then pls show some examples.

Comment: At least $r$ people should be there between any selected people and selected people are not counted as part of $r$

Comment: This question is extended version of (no two people should be adjacent) and i am curious to know how to solve them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the distance constraint, the answer would be $\binom{n}k$. Selections of people correspond to sequences of $k$ ones and $n-k$ zeroes.

To account for this new constraint, we need to ensure that there are at least $r$ zeroes in each of the $k-1$ gaps between the ones. So, set aside $r(k-1)$ zeroes, leaving $k$ ones and $n-k-r(k-1)$ zeroes. Arrange these remaining numbers in a line in $\binom{n-r(k-1)}{k}$ ways. Finally, insert $r$ zeroes into each of the $k-1$ regions between ones. This produces a selection where any two ones have at least $r$ zeroes between them, and every such selection is produced uniquely. Therefore, the number of ways is
$$
\binom{n-r(k-1)}{k}.
$$
**Edit:** For the circular variant,

- Set aside $kr$ zeroes, and $1$ one.
- Arrange the remaining numbers in a line, in $\binom{n-rk-1}{k-1}$ ways
- Place the one at the beginning of the line.
- Place $r$ zeroes after each of the $k$ ones.
- Arrange this list clockwise around the circle, in $n$ ways.

This seems to give a result of $n\binom{n-rk-1}{k-1}$. However, this procedure gives special treatment to the initally removed one, so there is overcounting by a factor of $k$. Therefore, the actual count is
$$
\frac{n}k\binom{n-rk-1}{k-1}
$$

Comment: Wow , nice explanation . Thanks a lot . Can we extend this to circular arrangement ?

Comment: @user1608 Yes you can, and it is only a small headache to do so. If you ask it as a separate question, I will answer.

Comment: @user1608 Actually, I just added the circular variant to this answer if you are still interested.

Comment: Thank you so much ... Clean explanation :)