# Probability that among $n$ random people, at least two have coinciding or successive birthdays

Tags: probability, puzzle, birthday

I found the following riddle:

> What is the probability that among $n$ people chosen randomly, at least two of them have their birthdays with **at most** one day difference.

Note: December 31 and January 1 are considered as having one day difference. For simplicity, we will consider that a year always contains 365 days.

I've found that the probability is

$$P\left( n\right) =
1-\prod\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n-1}
\left( 1-\frac{i}{365}\right) $$

Numerically, it gives the following (for example): $P\left( 14\right) \approx 53.75$, $P\left( 24\right) \approx 90.86$, and $P\left( 33\right) \approx 99.07$.

I'm not sure about my reasoning, since it is not rigorous and the results are quite surprising. So I wonder if anyone can check if these results are true and give a simple and comprehensive solution. Thank you!

Comment: Can we use $k$ or $n$ instead of $p$ for the number of people to not confuse with "probability" please?

Comment: Yes you can. @BenjaminWang

Comment: Are you familiar with how if we wanted a sequence of integers where the difference between terms is at least 2, we subtract $i$ from the $i$th term which gives us a sequence of distinct integers? Now, condition on whether day 1 is someone's birthday, or not.

Comment: I don't understand very well what you mean @CalvinLin

Comment: I don't think the formula is correct. This variation of the birthday paradox is going to be more complicated, because the exact values of the first $k$ birthdays is going to influence the probability that the $(k+1)$st birthday results in a coincidence. (Imagine if the first two birthdays are two days apart, for example.) I recommend working out the $n=3$ case extremely carefully to start with.

Comment: You calculate the probability that all birthdays are at least two days apart. For the first birthday, 365 choices. Second birthday, 362 choices. Third birthday, at least 359 but possibly 360 choices (unlikely). Assuming each birthday excludes three possible days you get a good lower bound for the probability that no two birthdays are close or an upper bound for the probability of two birthdays close together. Assuming that each birthday removes only two choices gives you a bound in the other direction.

Comment: Do you know how to use Stars and Bars to count the number of ways to pick $n$ distinct integers out of the first 365, so that no two are consecutive? The idea is to create a bijection to picking $n$ distinct integers out of the first $365-n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Let us find the complementary probability, that every pair of people's birthdays are at least two days apart. An equivalent problem is to find the probability that, when you select $n$ vertices independently and uniformly randomly from a polygon with $365$ vertices, that no two selected vertices are equal or adjacent.

A selection is described by a list $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$, where each $b_i\in \{1,2,\dots,365\}$. Since each selection is equally likely, in order find the probability, we just need to count the number of valid selections, then divide by the total number of selections. Using [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165170/number-of-ways-to-select-k-people-from-n-people-such-that-at-least-r-peopl/3165337#3165337), the number of ways to select $n$ distinct *unordered* points from a circle of $m$ points, such that no two are adjacent, is
$$
\frac{m}n\binom{m-n-1}{n-1}.
$$
Since we need to count *ordered* selections, we multiply this by $n!$. Finally, we divide by the total number of ways to assign birthdays to $n$ people, which is $365^n$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{no same or adjacent birthdays for $n$ people})
  &=(365)^{-n}\cdot \frac{365}{n}\binom{365-n-1}{n-1}\cdot n!
\\&=\frac{(365-n-1)!}{(365-2n)!(365)^{n-1}}
\\&=\prod_{i=n+1}^{2n-1}\frac{365-i}{365}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Mike Earnest has give an analytical proof of why your formula is correct.

Here is a simulation using R which shows (allowing for simulation noise) that your calculated probabilities seem reasonable:

```
anyclose <- function(people, days, close){
  birthdays <- sample(days, people, replace=TRUE)
  distances <- diff(c(sort(birthdays), min(birthdays)+days))
  return(any(distances <= close))
  }
  
set.seed(2024)
mean(replicate(10^5, anyclose(people=14, days=365, close=1))) 
# 0.53819 
mean(replicate(10^5, anyclose(people=24, days=365, close=1))) 
# 0.90837
mean(replicate(10^5, anyclose(people=33, days=365, close=1)))
# 0.99073
```

and just to show that this simulation also confirms the solution of the traditional birthday problem (with *close* then being the same birthday)

```
mean(replicate(10^5, anyclose(people=22, days=365, close=0)))
# 0.47757
mean(replicate(10^5, anyclose(people=23, days=365, close=0)))
# 0.50744
```

Comment: Thank you so much